# How do I get rid of Home in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I know this site is written using ASP.Net MVC and I do not see "/Home" in the url.  This proves to me that it can be done.  What special route and do I need?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just change "Home" to an empty string.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Home",
    "",
    new { action = Index, controller = Home }
);
```

Answer (score 8):

If you're running on IIS 7, you can simply delete the Default.aspx file that comes with ASP.NET MVC (assuming you're running on Preview 3 or higher). That file was needed due to an issue with Cassini that was fixed in .NET 3.5 SP1. For more details check out:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/04/10/upcoming-changes-in-routing.aspx
and
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/05/12/sp1-beta-and-its-effect-on-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 6):

I actually like having all of my home controller methods to be at the root of the site. Like this:  /about, /contact, etc.  I guess I'm picky.  I use a simple route constraint to do it.  [Here is my blog post with a code sample.](http://sonerdy.com/getting-rid-of-home-in-aspnet-mvc)

Answer (score 1):

I'd add

```
routes.MapRoute("NoIndex", "{action}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

in RouteConfig.cs

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to get rid of Home.  It will treat all routes with only one specifier as Home/Action and any with two as Controller/Action.  The downside is now controller has to have an explicit index (/Controller != /Controller/Index), but it might help you or others.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{action}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Actions",
    "{controller}/{action}",
    new { }
);
```

Answer (score -2):

In IIS 7, you can simply delete the Default.aspx file that comes with ASP.NET MVC (assuming you're running on Preview 3 or higher). That file was needed due to an issue with Cassini that was fixed in .NET 3.5 SP1.

For more details check out:

[Upcoming Changes In Routing](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/04/10/upcoming-changes-in-routing.aspx)  and  [.NET 3.5 SP1 Beta and Its Effect on MVC](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/05/12/sp1-beta-and-its-effect-on-mvc.aspx)