# ASP.net MVC HomeController URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc

By default the MVC Preview 5 web project comes with a HomeController.vb class.  This sets the web URL to http://www.mywebsite.com/home/ by default.  If I just wanted this to be http://www.mywebsite.com/ by default, how would I accomplish that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get rid of Home in ASP.Net MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470/how-do-i-get-rid-of-home-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answered already so I'm just going to direct you to [How do I get rid of Home in ASP.Net MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470/how-do-i-get-rid-of-home-in-aspnet-mvc).

<sup>Users with 10k+ rep can also refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33861/aspnet-mvc-routing-basics-root-route (deleted)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question, if what you want is to go to http://www.mywebsite.com/ and not have it be trailed by /home, that is the behavior you will get.

Is there something else you were looking for?